# names won't display correctly and changing status bar color

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to display a full of name a user. This is my code:

```
render(){
return(
  <List containerStyle={{borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0}}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({item})=>(
        <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        title={'${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}'}
        subtitle={item.email}
        avatar={{uri: item.picture.thumbnail}}
        containerStyle={{borderBottomWidth: 0}}
      />
    )}
    keyExtractor={item=>item.email}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
    ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
    />
  </List>
);
}
```

but for reason the title is presented as 'item.name.first item.name.last' instead the real first and last name of the user. What am I doing wrong?

Another question, How can I use StatusBar in this render method to change the color of my status bar?

I tried adding it before list but it is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `'` with `.

```
title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
```

Example:

```
  render() {
    let firstName = 'test';
    let lastName = 'testing';
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{`${firstName} ${lastName}` } </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Output:

test testing